# How to convert values between 2 columns into csv text

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table where we store the data similar to the following (Starttime and Endtime both are varchar2):

```
StartTime EndTime
00:30      07:30
16:00      19:00
.           .
.           .
.           .
```

What I want to do is to convert this to corresponding half hourly numbers so:

```
00:00 becomes x1 
00:30 x2
01:00 x3
01:30 x4
..
```

*Midnight (00:00 is x1 and 23:30 is 48)*

**What I have done with the below SQL:**

```
Select StartTime, EndTime, 
    Case StartTime
        When '00:00' Then 'x1'
        When '00:30' Then 'x2' ....
    End StartTime_x
    Case EndTime
        When '00:00' Then 'x1'
        When '00:30' Then 'x2' ....
    End EndTime_x
From myTable
```

**It is giving me this:**

```
StartTime, EndTime, StartTime_x, EndTime_x
16:00      19:00    x33          x39
19:00      20:00    x39          x41
```

**What I am trying to achieve is this:**

```
StartTime, EndTime, StartTime_x, EndTime_x    Range
16:00      19:00    x33          x39           x33,x34,x35,x36,x37,x38,x39   
19:00      20:00    x39          x41           x39,x40,x41
```

How can I traverse between starttime_x and endtime_x values and create csv values of what's between them?

Comment: do u want to do this in  sql alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you're over-complicating things with your CASE statement. You can use maths instead, more specifically the fact that Oracle returns a number when doing date arithmetic. Furthermore, converting to a date ensures that you're doing your arithmetic correctly. It's all to easy to make a typo in a large CASE statement like that, which means that everything will be wrong. This solution will deal with any time of the day, not just the specific half-hours.

If I set-up a table as follows:

```
create table times ( starttime varchar2(5), endtime varchar2(5) );
insert into times values ( '00:30','07:30');
insert into times values ( '16:00','19:00');
insert into times values ( '19:00','20:00');
```

The following query will get you most of the way there:

```
SQL> select starttime
          , endtime
          , trunc( ( to_date(starttime,'hh24:mi') 
                  - trunc(sysdate) ) * 48) + 1 as starttime_x
          , trunc( ( to_date(endtime,'hh24:mi') 
                  - trunc(sysdate) ) * 48) + 1 as endtime_x
       from times;

START ENDTI STARTTIME_X  ENDTIME_X
----- ----- ----------- ----------
00:30 07:30       1     16
16:00 19:00      33     39
19:00 20:00      39     41
```

You then need to add a comma-delimited list of all the values in the range. I would avoid this if at all possible... it won't be of much use to you and will only be okay for displaying. However, this data is implied in the difference between `starttime_x` and `endtime_x` and so I don't see what benefit it brings.

However, assuming you *have* to do it you will have to generate the rows between the start and end ranges and then aggregate them.

```
SQL> with the_times as ( 
  select starttime
       , endtime
       , trunc( ( to_date(starttime,'hh24:mi') 
               - trunc(sysdate) ) * 48) + 1 as starttime_x
       , trunc( ( to_date(endtime,'hh24:mi') 
                - trunc(sysdate) ) * 48) + 1 as endtime_x
    from times
         )
 , all_times as (
  select level as t
    from dual
 connect by level <= 48
         )
 select starttime, endtime
      , 'x' || starttime_x as starttime_x, 'x' || endtime_x as endtime_x
      , listagg('x' || t, ', ') within group ( order by t ) as range
   from ( select a.*, b.t
            from the_times a
           cross join all_times b
           where b.t between a.starttime_x and a.endtime_x
                 )
  group by starttime, endtime, 'x' || starttime_x, 'x' || endtime_x;

STARTTIME ENDTIME STA END RANGE
--------- ------- --- --- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
00:30     07:30   x1  x16 x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16
16:00     19:00   x33 x39 x33, x34, x35, x36, x37, x38, x39
19:00     20:00   x39 x41 x39, x40, x41
```

As you can see this is not particularly pretty...

Please note that I added the `x` afterwards. Adding arbitrary characters to numbers only serves to make and arithmetic you have to do more difficult. Adding it at the end is a way around this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the firsts part worked like a charm but I got an error on the listagg line.  I just did: select banner from v$version; and realized the database is 10g and not 11g, edited the tags. Is there a workaround this for 10g?

Comment: Yes, you can use the undocumented function `wm_concat` or the Tom Kyte's user defined function `stragg`. All the string aggregation techniques available are described [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution in SQL

The table I created with the values inserted for test are:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable AS
Select '00:30' As Starttime, '02:30' As Endtime FROM dual
Union All
Select '01:00' As Starttime, '04:00' As Endtime FROM dual
Union All
Select '00:00' As Starttime, '03:30' As Endtime FROM dual;
```

Here is the query to return data in the format you're expecting

```
Select X.Starttime,X.Endtime,X.Starttime_X,X.Endtime_X, Listagg(X.Abc,',') Within Group (Order By X.Starttime) 
FROM
(
Select distinct a.*, 'x'||(LEVEL + (TO_NUMBER(substr(starttime_x,INSTR(starttime_x,'x',1)+1))) -1) as abc
From (Select StartTime, EndTime, 
    Case StartTime
        When '00:00' Then 'x1'
        When '00:30' Then 'x2' 
        When '01:00' Then 'x3'
        When '01:30' Then 'x4'
        When '02:00' Then 'x5'
        When '02:30' Then 'x6'
        When '03:00' Then 'x7'
        When '03:30' Then 'x8'
        When '04:00' Then 'x9'
        When '04:30' Then 'x10'
        When '05:00' Then 'x11'
        WHEN '05:30' THEN 'x12'
    End StartTime_x,
    Case EndTime
        When '00:00' Then 'x1'
        When '00:30' Then 'x2' 
        When '01:00' Then 'x3'
        When '01:30' Then 'x4'
        When '02:00' Then 'x5'
        When '02:30' Then 'x6'
        When '03:00' Then 'x7'
        When '03:30' Then 'x8'
        When '04:00' Then 'x9'
        When '04:30' Then 'x10'
        When '05:00' Then 'x11'
        WHEN '05:30' THEN 'x12'
    End Endtime_X
    From Mytable) A
    Connect By Level <= (To_Number(Substr(Endtime_X,Instr(Endtime_X,'x',1)+1)) - To_Number(Substr(Starttime_X,Instr(Starttime_X,'x',1)+1))) + 1
    ) X
    GROUP BY x.starttime, x.endtime,X.Starttime_X,X.Endtime_x;
```

The output is:

```
00:00   03:30   x1  x8  x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8
00:30   02:30   x2  x6  x2,x3,x4,x5,x6
01:00   04:00   x3  x9  x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9
```

Comment: Incognito:gud thinking dude

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is on oracle 10g I have added the solution here based on Ben's answer above:

I have simply changed the listagg with wm_concat:

```
with the_times as ( 
  select starttime
       , endtime
       , trunc( ( to_date(starttime,'hh24:mi') 
               - trunc(sysdate) ) * 48) + 1 as starttime_x
       , trunc( ( to_date(endtime,'hh24:mi') 
                - trunc(sysdate) ) * 48) + 1 as endtime_x
    from times
         )
 , all_times as (
  select level as t
    from dual
 connect by level <= 48
         )
select starttime, endtime
      , 'x' || starttime_x as starttime_x, 'x' || endtime_x as endtime_x
      , wm_concat('x' || t)  as range
   from ( select a.*, b.t
            from the_times a
           cross join all_times b
           where b.t between a.starttime_x and a.endtime_x
                 )
  group by starttime, endtime, 'x' || starttime_x, 'x' || endtime_x;
```